# Android Instant App : Feature module : The module cannot be android library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-apps, gradle-3.0

I started converting my app to support [instant feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cosqlfqrpFA), following the **[Google IO tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/#0)**. I got the build running correctly. I've disabled `aapt2` and `enableNewResourceProcessing` as i was running into build *errors*. The module builds without *errors* after disabling those two `flags` but when i go to *edit configuration* of the **base Feature** of the app i get `The module cannot be android library`.

Does anyone know what causes this issue. I'm using `com.android.feature plugin` in the feature module's build along with *build flavours* and *build types*.

Comment: What is the value of `apply plugin [..]` in your module level build.gradle?

Comment: `com.android.feature`

Comment: Are  you using build tools 26.0.0-rc1 or above? Also, you'll need to use aapt2. Can you tell what errors did you see with aapt2?

Comment: I've changed to 26 but no success. I was using 25. With aapt2 i get ` uncompiled XML file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file.` The stacktrace is too big but `Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:` and `ERROR:  failed parsing overlays` are the prominant error messages

Comment: Should i ask a question for aapt2 error ?

Comment: I removed the build configuration for feature all together ... it was my mistake ... while make the app instant enabled i have refactored and accidentally removed launcher activity. Its working fine now ... Guess i should delete the question ?

Comment: You could answer your own question and then mark the answer as resolved.

Comment: @BruceWayne can you give me more details? I'm experiencing this issue and I haven't found any solutions for it. Submit your solution as a detailed answer so other users + me can see what have you done to fix this issue. Thanks :)

Comment: @ArdaÇebi submitted the solution

Answer (score -1):

A feature module is treated as a library. It doesn't have an application ID. So, "The module cannot be android library" error is generated.

Answer (score -1):

The problem I was facing was that there was a build configuration for the instant feature as well. Since each instant feature is considered as an android library, Studio throws errors saying `module cannot be android library`. To solve this i simply removed the build configuration via

`Run -> Edit configuration -> Click on - button`

Keep your base app module configuration and delete all other feature configurations.

Answer (score -1):

Don't run your `feature`. Run your `instantapp` instead and set feature URL in it:

> Run -> Edit Configurations -> Android App -> instantapp -> General -> Launch Options -> Launch = URL -> URL = https://example.com/my_feature